# How to use verse library in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, xmpp, coronasdk

i have searched how to implement chat application in CORONA SDK using XMPP.Found verse is the lua language to implement chat application.
i searched about
[Verse](http://matthewwild.co.uk/projects/verse/verse_doc.xml).i found some lua [file](https://github.com/hpychan/verse/blob/master/doc/example.lua).but cannot undarstand how to use.please anyone instruct me to start using verse in corona sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin:
https://docs.coronalabs.com/plugin/photon/
It is a lot easier.